# Как убрать растушевку краев изображения при размытии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlabel, qgraphicsblureffect

Я применяю эффект размытия к виджету `back_picture`, который представляет собой изображение.

Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно, что края изображения размываются, из-за чего появляется темная рамка. Мне нужно как-то избавиться от этой рамки, иначе говоря, сделать края изображения четкими. Для того, чтобы было немного понятнее, я нарисовал картинку `как сейчас/как надо`. Вот она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, можно избавиться от растушевки краев путем уменьшения области размытия. Но это не лучший способ, т.к., если сильно уменьшить область размытия, то будет заметно, что не все изображение размыто, а это совсем мне не подходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как оставить края изображения четкими при размытии изображения?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.addWidget(btn)        
        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('picture3.jpg', 300, self.container)
        self.back_picture.move(0, 0)

        blur_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius = 3)
        self.back_picture.setGraphicsEffect(blur_effect)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture2.png') 
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture1.png') 
            self.index = 1


qss = '''QLabel {
             color: red;
             font: bold 16px;
             background: transparent;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD:**
Вот картинка, обложка к музыкальному альбому Linkin Park - The Hunting Party

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваше реальное изображение, на котором хорошо видно, что вам не нравится. Какой значение вы хотите использовать в `blurRadius=7` ?

Comment: Я добавил картинку и скажу, на всякий случай, что предсказать и отредактировать картинку заранее я не могу, т.к. изображения извлекаются из тегов MP3-файла. Не совсем понял, что значит `blurRadius=7`, т.к. в коде число 3. Не могли бы вы объяснить это?

Comment: Перечитал ваш комментарий. Вы говорили про изображение приложения? Если да, то сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно вас понимаю, но попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.addWidget(btn)        
        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)


#        self.back_picture = BackPicture('lena.jpg', 300, self.container)
#        self.back_picture.move(0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('lena.jpg', 310, self.container)            # +++
        self.back_picture.move(-5, -5)                                              # +++ 


        blur_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=3)        
        self.back_picture.setGraphicsEffect(blur_effect)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('img/LinkinPark1.jpg') 
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('img/LinkinPark2.png') 
            self.index = 1


qss = '''QLabel {
             color: red;
             font: bold 16px;
             background: transparent;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо. Да, все верно, я говорил именно про эти полосы :)

Comment: Добрый вечер. Я понимаю, что, скорее всего, вас обижаю, когда обращаюсь лично, да, так делать нехорошо. Но сейчас хотелось бы знать стоит ли мне ждать ответ на последний вопрос? Ни в коем случае не говорю, что вы чего-то должны. Просто мне нужно понимать, какие действия стоит предпринять дальше. Это очень сильно зависит от того, будет ли дан ответ или нет. К сожалению, я очень несамостоятельный в этом деле. Может быть, мой вопрос некорректный? Если да, пожалуйста, напишите почему. Это очень важно. Прошу прощения за то, что вынужден тратить ваше время. Пожалуйста, не обижайтесь на меня

Comment: @MAXIM045 вопрос для меня не простой. Быстрого ответа не ждете. Пробуйте другие варианты, продолжайте действовать. Попробуйте сделать перевод на английский и опубликовать вопрос на https://stackoverflow.com/ там есть несколько гуру, которые могут подсказать направление, если им вопрос понравится.

Comment: Подумаю о переводе, но, когда я писал вопрос на русском, своем родном языке, довольно долго думал, как лучше объяснить некоторые вещи. Английский я не знаю абсолютно, поэтому, скорее всего, ничего у меня не выйдет :( Большое вам спасибо за ответ! Не думал, что так быстро попаду в тупик

Comment: @MAXIM045 это не тупик, всегда есть то или иное решение. Вопрос изложен, в принципе, понятно. `Google translate` вам поможет. Напишите: "Sorry, за мой плохой английский ..."

Comment: Вроде я разобрался. Оставил свой ответ :)